# Raspberry pi modbus on rj45

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2, modbus, modbus-tcp

Hi there (I apologize for my english, that not my native lang)
I have a sort of "blackbox" who send me data trought a RJ45 port, in a [MODBUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modbus) format and I want to read the data with my Raspberry Pi 2.
I searched a lot on google, but the only solutions for listening a modbus is to put a card on top of my RPI2, using the RX/TX ports, that I dont want...
If someone have a solution, thanks !

Comment: You'll need to provide more information here before anyone can help. Is the RJ45 port an Ethernet connection? In that case is the device sending MODBUS TCP, or MODBUS over TCP? If so you should be able to connect it to your Pi's Ethernet port via a hub or crossover cable and read the data that way.

Comment: Thanks for reply @nekomatic !
I really don't know, that the problem, but I think our prototype was dead, we saw an IP on the box and nothing output from ping/listening...
But, anyway, the project is over so I won't touch it anymore :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, my project is over, the "black box" prototype didn't even send electric output, and the project is over now.
Closing this :)